# webgate and cx_Oracle InterfaceError: Unable to acquire Oracle environment handle;

Tags: python, oracle, apache

I am trying integrate webgate + apache24 on Oracle Linux 7. 
The webgate + apache24 integration works fine with static pages (for e.g. index.html).

Also, when i try to serve the API using with python + mod wsgi + apache (without webgate) it works fine. Apache is able to get the environment handle.

But when i enable the webgate.conf in apache httpd.conf, the cx_oracle start complaining about cx_Oracle InterfaceError: Unable to acquire Oracle environment handle;

I have set the env variable in /etc/sysconfig/httpd

```
export ORACLE_HOME=<path to oracle_home>
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<path to oracle_home>:/opt/Python-3.5.2/lib
export LD_RUN_PATH=<path to oracle_home>
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/<path to oracle_home>/webgate/apache/lib/
```

i have also set these in /etc/profile and restarted apache still it does not work.

When i print os.environ in app.py that is loaded using mod_wsgi, I do see all the above vaiable set.

Additional information, i have modified the /etc/httpd/conf/http.conf , 'User' directive to 'localuser'

However i still continue get the same error. Not quite sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

With OL7 / RHEL7 the syntax for /etc/sysconfig/httpd is now like:

```
ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1
```

etc.

Note

- there is no `export` keyword
- I believe you can't use variables on the right hand side of the equal sign.

Comment: Hi Christorpher, I have tried this but has not worked.